# A question regarding a possible misprint on showing why a part bertrands lemma leads to a certain result

Tags: number-theory

I got a question in an assignment but I'm sure it has to be a misprint, any clarification on this would be much appreciated ( though I want to work the actual problem out myself)

It's about Bertrands postulate, particularly we've been asked to consider the lemma which states that for $n>2$ and $\tfrac{2n}{3}<p\leq n$, $p$ does not divide $\pmatrix{2n\\n}$, and then explain why this means that all prime factors of $\pmatrix{2n\\n}$ satisfy $p\leq \tfrac{2n}{3}$.

but then take for example $n=3$ then  $\pmatrix{2n\\n}$= $\pmatrix{6\\3}=\tfrac{6.5.4.3.2.1}{3.2.1.3.2.1.}=\tfrac{6.5.4}{3.2}=5.2^2$ and so 5 appears in the prime decomposition. But then this contradicts what we were trying to show because $\tfrac{2n}{3}=\tfrac{6}{3}=2$and 5 is certainly not less than 2. Surely the thing we should be trying to show is that $p\geq\tfrac{2n}{3}$ , no ?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is correct that $\binom{2n}{n}$ has no prime factor $p$ such that $\frac{2n}3 \lt p \le n$.
It follows that all prime factors $p$ are either $\le \frac{2n}3$ or greater than $n$.  As you've seen with $n = 3$, both cases can occur.

Since the intent is to prove Bertrand's postulate, i.e., that there is some prime between $n$ and $2n$, I suspect the plan was to assume the contrary and eventually arrive at a contradiction.  Under this assumption, all prime factors of $\binom{2n}{n}$ must be either $\le \frac{2n}3$ or greater than $2n$.  If that is what's going on, your next step is simply to eliminate the possibility that $p \gt 2n$.  That isn't hard.  The difficult step is to show that the contribution of the primes $\lt \frac{2n}3$ is not actually large enough to produce $\binom{2n}{n}$, yielding the desired contradiction.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, we don't actually have to prove bertrands postulate, just explain why the part of the lemma I stated means that $p\leq\tfrac{2n}{3}$. But I assume your answer is still what I would need to use to explain this